# whenever i'm trying to run my code in emulator it is showing apps keeps stopping and in error i'm getting in setcontentview(R.layout.Main_activity)

Tags: java, r.java-file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
TextView txtSlogan;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);

    txtSlogan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/NABILA.TTF");
    txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signIn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignIn.class);
            startActivity(signIn);
```

The error message is as follows

> ```
> 08-04 21:02:59.089 12196-12196/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
>     at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
>         ... 30 more
> 2019-08-04 21:03:01.319 1886-5478/? E/UsageStatsDatabase: Unexpected event timestamp 945328593 loaded (beginTime : 1564916017123, endTime : 1564932059648)
> Error found in:
> /data/system/usagestats/0/daily/1564916017123
> Please go to b/115429334 to help root cause this issue
> 2019-08-04 21:03:01.319 1886-5478/? E/UsageStatsService: Recent UsageStats missing! timeRange : 1564932779181, 1564932781315
> Last reported Usage Event time : 1564932779181
> Last in memory event time : 1564932779181
> Last save time: 1564932063000
> Last on disk event time : 1564932059648
> 2019-08-04 21:03:02.558 1886-1906/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
> 2019-08-04 21:03:02.594 12241-12241/? E/com.bnb.quicke: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
> 2019-08-04 21:03:02.932 1682-1682/? E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: No such process
> 2019-08-04 21:03:03.056 1683-1866/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
> 2019-08-04 21:03:03.060 12241-12271/? E/vndksupport: Could not load /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found.
> 2019-08-04 21:03:03.061 12241-12271/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): unknown
> 2019-08-04 21:03:03.271 12241-12241/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.bnb.quicker, PID: 12241
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bnb.quicker/com.bnb.quicker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.bnb.quicker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #40 in com.bnb.quicker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.bnb.quicker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #40 in com.bnb.quicker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40 in com.bnb.quicker:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
>  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:869)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1021)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:976)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1138)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1141)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1099)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:549)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
>     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>     at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>     at com.bnb.quicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7698)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7687)
>     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3096)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:81)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1935)
> ```

Comment: add your XML activity

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the library you are getting the `FButton` from is the problem:

```
Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
```

Somebody has already fixed it in his library, just use `'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'` ([source](https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button)) as a dependency instead of the currently used android flat button library.

You can follow the project's [issue](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/issues/41) to get more information if needed.